# Android AlertDialog tutorial gives an error - Blank Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The android documentation on [dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) gives a nice little tutorial on `AlertDialogs`. Immediately when using the code I get an error in Eclipse on `getActivity()`. Why doesn't this work? Error: `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity` This is especially confusing for someone that is trying to read through the documentation to become a better programmer overall, but it seems like I'm not connecting the dots on something. Thanks.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as doc says :

[getActivity (Context con, int reqCode, Intent intent, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new activity, like calling
>   Context.startActivity(Intent). Note that the activity will be started
>   outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the
>   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent.

and about

```
[public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context)][2]

Constructor using a context for this builder and the AlertDialog it creates.
```

means *AlertDialog.Builder Constructor require an Context instance instead of PendingIntent*

change your code as:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

**EDIT :**

as link provided by you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

in this example writer talking about how we show `AlertDialog` from `DialogFragment` .we when use `getActivity()` inside `DialogFragment` it return *an Activity this fragment is currently associated with*.  mean indirectly [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) returning an Context instance

Answer (score 1):

you're not building against the right api.. the method `getActivity()` is not available in previous APIs. you can always go for

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

or when calling from an inner class, use

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);`

instead